# Передать переменную из @override метода в класс

Tags: java

Допустим есть вот такой метод и из него нужно передать в main перемененную order:

```
  @Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    Message massage = update.getMessage();
    String order ;
```

Comment: Так не получится. Определите новый метод, который вернет ваш `order`. Собственно, что вам мешает определить еще один метод, который будет возвращать результат?

Comment: Самое простое решение - сделать переменную `order` полем класса (доступной всем областям видимости в классе), а вообще по возврату значений из колбэка [вот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451206/177345). Обязательно посмотрите и второй ответ по существенной проблеме через возврат значения в поле класса.

Answer (score 0):

Если main() вызывает ваш метод, который должен возвращать ему какое-то значение, то в сигнатуре вашего метода должен быть не void, а тип возвращаемого значения. И в теле метода должно присутствовать волшебное слова return. Ну, и, конечно, ваш метод должен быть static

```
@Override
public static String onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    Message massage = update.getMessage();
    String order = "" ;
return order;
}
```

Comment: Это будет уже не переопределенный метод, так как его сигнатура не будет совпадать с переопределяемым и компилятор выдаст предупреждение об этом, а программа не скомпилируется

Comment: Ну, а кто мешает чутка подправить оригинальный метод?

Comment: Метод API или фреймворка? Судя по имени метода это вообще колбэк системы на какое то обновление запроса. Если вы считаете такое решение возможным, то расскажите подробнее, как вы предлагаете "чутка подправлять" системные колбэки

Comment: о том, что это речи не велось... может у человека вообще учебная задача...